# How can I parse the following httpresponse and also what is the best method to parse it?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, httpresponse

```
<catalog><channel><id>4</id>
<name>News</name>
<shortDescription>News happens!</shortDescription>
<subscribe>true</subscribe></channel>
<channel><id>10</id>
<name>Jokes</name>
<shortDescription>funny jokes!</shortDescription>  
</channel>
<channel><id>5</id><name>Markets</name<keyword>cc-markets</keyword>  
<shortDescription>Track the market's movers & shakers at-a-glance.</shortDescription> 
</channel>
</catalog>
```

I want to get the data between the tag "name", I have many tags with the name "name" but all the tags are not being parsed, the xml is being parsed only till the tag with data "Markets", this has been frustrating me for quite some time now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of alternatives

[xmlpullparser](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/pull-parser.html)

[SAXParser](http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html)

DomParser

etc.,

Here is interesting ibm article on [xml parsers in android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

Comment: I know but the SAX parser doesn't parse the data after the special character "&", I had tough time with DOM parser too. What will be the best approach?

Comment: Here is SO discussion on how to handle "&" character while SAX parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798411/how-to-read-escaped-characters-using-sax-parser-in-characters-method

Comment: SO should I go ahead with SAXparsing?

Comment: I don't see any issues with it. Based on your requirement you may decide one of those.

Comment: Go for SAX Parser there is a way to parse special characters in the SAX Parser

Comment: @thinksteep still the whole data is not being parsed.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Update latest code and error.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two possible xml parsers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

http://www.bearcave.com/software/java/xml/xmlpull.html

Comment: I'm new to parsing can you help me out with the code for my xml?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently SAXParser doesn't parse special characters such as "'" and "&" instead it uses "'" and "&" in place of them. So all I did was replacing these characters with their xml counterparts that is it.