# Java : how to extract data from text area that contain XML string

Tags: java, sax

I have a TextArea that have this XML text  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>  
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
   <entry key="MULTI">2</entry>
   <entry key="MULTI2">2</entry>
</properties>
```

How can I get the two values of : multi1 , multi2 as a variable inside java preferred using sax parser?

*I'm working on NetBeans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Text Nodes From XML File Using SAX Parser in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527506/extracting-text-nodes-from-xml-file-using-sax-parser-in-java)

Comment: no , its not , my XML is different